# Возможно ли создать бота для сбора уведомлений?

Tags: бот, уведомления, автоматизация

У меня появилась идея создания телеграмм бота для сбора уведомлений на сайтах лично мне интересных, но не имеющих возможности отправлять уведомления на почту или куда-нибудь ещё(у меня много таких сайтов, и хотелось бы смотреть все уведомления в 1м месте). Так вот, я не хочу подстраивать код под каждый сайт и хотел узнать возможно вообще как-то подстроить шаблон таким образом(я планирую использовать Selenium) что бы в нем изменять только названия кнопок, полей ввода и подобных элементов. Ведь дня навигации на сайтах с моего аккаунта нужна навигация по сайту(авторизация, переход на друге страницы и т.д.), а названия элементов везде разное.
И появился вопрос, возможно ли это вообще?

Answer (score 0):

Для каждого сайта нужно писать свой модуль. Не получится сделать типовой селениум, который будет следить за всеми сразу.